Unable to run solaris 10 on qemu-sparc64
I am trying to run solaris 10 OS on qemu-sparc64 emulator with command:
qemu-system-sparc64 -M sun4u -m 3048 
-drive file=sparc.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=0,unit=0,media=disk 
-cdrom sol-10-u11-ga-sparc-dvd.iso 
-boot d 
-nographic
The execution reaches the language selection and then hangs:

At this point I can't type on the keyboard because it's frozen.

Solaris 10 dropped support for earlier SPARC CPUs.  Does either of the later CPU architectures sun4v or niagara work?

No, It does not work. @AndrewHenle

-M sun4v - qemu: fatal: Trap 0x0010 while trap level (6) >= MAXTL (6), Error state

-M niagara - rom: file nvram1              : error Failed to open file “nvram1”: No such file or directory

I believe -append -v will boot the Solaris kernel in verbose mode.  That might help.

@AndrewHenle How to properly use it? It gives me "-append only allowed with -kernel option" error
